# open atrium features

Tags: distributions

I installed Open Atrium, and there are no default features showing under the features admin panel. No shoutbox, wiki, blog or calendar. Did I choose a stripped down version of Open Atrium to install by accident?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to turn those features on if you'd like to use them.

Create a group and then in that group go to Settings -> Customize Features, here you can enable the features you need.

Comment: that's what I am saying not that they are not enabled but are not even included in the package I downloaded from open atrium. I see nothing at Settings -> Customize Features, and my install of open atrium sites/all/modules folder is empty

Comment: I see on the screenshot that you are on the wrong place. You have to create a group and then find the Customize Features in that group's settings.

In OpenAtrium you can create multiple groups for multiple users and each group can be set up differently. For one group maybe just Notebook needed, for another maybe all features needed, we have the ability to customize them.

Comment: /admin/build/features here all features say default but can not add to dashboard do I have to add a group first?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a group first. Go to front page -> Groups -> Add group to create a group, the rest is described in the second comment.